# Regex str_replace

Tags: php, mysql, regex, url, str-replace

Would it be possible to incorporate a `str_replace` method with a regular expression, designed to catch url strings in a simple html < textfield > input type?

I'm considering something simple like a tip for the user to set it up as follows:

*This is some text and click this link [**here**](http://www.google.com).*

Obviously the word "here" is a href to the url before it (or after it, if that makes a difference). The text input is drawn from a MySQL db.

I believe the start of my solution is something along the lines of:

```
$regex = '';
$pg = $row['pg'];
$pg = str_replace('{regex goes here}', $pg);
```

But I know things are missing. 
And then I would just output the $pg paragraph.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check out `preg_replace` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), this is what you are lookin for.

```
// From the documentation.
preg_replace($regularExpression, $replacement, $subject);
```

Comment: It is indeed, but I am unsure of how to replace my entire string with just the word in the 2nd part of the string, enclosed in an <a>-tag. I don't see how I replace a dynamic string with anything other than a static string. And I need the replacement to also be dynamic.

Comment: lol you have no clue how many times I've searched this in the 6 years I've been a php developer, it's sad...

Answer (score 12):

What you're looking for is [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$pg = preg_replace('{regex goes here}', '{replacement goes here}', $pg);
```