# PHP - Search and replace tags with links

Tags: php

I'm a little new to PHP development so I am just trying a few basic things currently.

I have a PHP website with a few pages. What I would like to create is a script that links any content with hashtags I write to link to Twitter.

So for example if I have a page with #wednesday on it, the script will pick that up and link the hashtag to that search on Twitter automatically.

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, but I'd really appreciate tips and what functions you would consider using to go about creating something simple like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Regex, that would do the job... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528337/regex-str-replace

Comment: Have you already tried something yourself?

Comment: can you please show us what the desired output would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex for that:

```
$newContent = preg_replace(
   '/#(\w+)/',
   '<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>',
   $content
);
```

Here:

`/#(\w+)/` means find any word that starts with `#`
`<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>` replacement and `$1` means found hash tag.
`$content` content where to replace hash tags

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/eG2qN0/1